# Loss of FPS using mask

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

'm working on an application which allows to make image processing, so I used Javascript and PixiJS library to make it possible. I wanted to update cursor image when canvas was hovered

**first solution** I tried to use cursor: url(cursor1.png) 4 12, auto; but I can't resize cursor. The default size is 64px and I can't set another value.

**second solution** I decided to add into DOM  and update x,y position using Javascript but I got latency.

**third solution** was to integrate cursor inside my canvas.

last solution I tried to split actions into 2 canvas. The first deals with image processing and the second is my cursor.

With all propositions made before I got loss of FPS when canvas is hovered excepted the first one.

## Init main canvas for image processing

```
function _initMainCanvas(imgData) {
  let newCanvas = new PIXI.Application({
    width: imgData.width,
    height: imgData.height,
    transparent: true
  });

  let blurContainer = new PIXI.Container();

  filters.initFilters();

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //      Normal Sprite
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  let bg = main.createSprite({
    from: imgData.img,
    interactive: true,
    filters: [filters.getFilterSharpen(), filters.getFilterAdjustment()],
    width: imgData.width,
    height: imgData.height
  });
  newCanvas.stage.addChild(bg);

  //$(".blur_cursor").remove();

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //      Blur Sprite
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  let bgBlured = main.createSprite({
    from: imgData.img,
    interactive: false,
    filters: filters.getFilters(),
    width: imgData.width,
    height: imgData.height
  });
  blurContainer.addChild(bgBlured);
  blurContainer.mask = containers.getBlurs();

  newCanvas.stage.addChild(blurContainer);
  newCanvas.stage.addChild(blurContainer);

  select.initSelectionRect();
  newCanvas.stage.addChild(select.getSelectionRect());

  canvas.addMainCanvas(newCanvas);
  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(newCanvas.view);
}
```

## Init canvas for cursor update when mouse hover it

```
function _initCursorCanvas(imgData) {
  let cursorCanvas = new PIXI.Application({
    width: imgData.width,
    height: imgData.height,
    transparent: true
  });

  _fillCursorCanvas(cursorCanvas);

  canvas.addCursorCanvas(cursorCanvas);

  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(cursorCanvas.view);
}

function _fillCursorCanvas(cursorCanvas) {
  // emptySprite allows to bind events
  let emptySprite = new PIXI.Sprite();
  emptySprite.interactive = true;
  emptySprite.width = cursorCanvas.screen.width;
  emptySprite.height = cursorCanvas.screen.height;
  cursorCanvas.stage.addChild(emptySprite);

  emptySprite
    .on("pointerdown", canvasEvents.handlerMousedown)
    .on("pointerup", canvasEvents.handlerMouseup)
    .on("pointermove", canvasEvents.handlerMousemove)
    .on("pointerout", canvasEvents.handlerMouseout);

  const scale = W / canvas.getWidth();
  const cursorTexture = new PIXI.Texture.from(
    urlManager.replace("index.php/", "") + "assets/images/cursor_img/50.png"
  );

  let circle = new PIXI.Sprite(cursorTexture);
  circle.width = 50 / scale;
  circle.height = 50 / scale;

  cursorCanvas.stage.addChild(circle);
}
```

## Mousemove event

```
const x = e.data.global.x;
const y = e.data.global.y;

cursor.updatePosition(x, y, W);
```

Will anyone know how to optimize FPS on mouse flying, thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a second canvas just for that?
If you want to update the cursor do it at the end of the update loop and that's it, don't make a new canvas just for that.

Comment: I had tested to add to the main canvas but I got loss of FPS too, so I thought that creatng new canvas layrer it will be better but it's not the case. Do you have any suggestions ? I noticed that I got loss FPS using mask with pixijs

Comment: i agree with @Denis Ambrus that it shouldnt require second canvas just to handle cursor.

Comment: @heticWyllis additional questions: Can you also show what `cursor.updatePosition` is doing? How your rendering loop looks?

It would be best if you create working example on jsfiddle, codesandbox or pixiplayground.com - then we could see whole picture, and propose concrete fixes.

Comment: Sorry @domis86 I tried use codesandbox but my browser was not responding, so I can't show you an example. In `cursor.updatePosition` I got :  ```const canvasChild = 
    canvas.getCursorCanvas().stage.children;
    const last = canvasChild.length - 1;

    canvasChild[last].position.x = x;
    canvasChild[last].position.y = y;```. I can send you github repo ? Thanks a lot

Comment: @heticWyllis if you try to disable (comment out) everything except cursor (and empty sprite) - is it still slow?

Comment: it's cursor that is slow not all canvas